# Como realizar una Transaccion en MySql Desde una aplicación en C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, transacciones

Ojala puedan ayudarme, estoy realizando un modelo de ventas en C# y estoy tratando de aplicar la atomicidad de una Transacción cuando finalizo la venta.

Por lo que he leído en Internet hay una Clase llamada MySqlTransacction que ayuda a este proceso, alguien ya la ha usado? he tratado de buscar ejemplos para estudiarlos pero no encuentro mucho.

Agradecería si alguien me pudiera orientar o dar algún ejemplo de como poder hacer esto.

Soy nuevo en esto así que agradezco cualquier comentario o consejo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar MySqlTransaction, aqui te dejo un ejemplo.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Defines la variable
            MySqlTransaction tr = null;
            try
            {
                // Abres la conexion
                conn.Open();
                // Inicializas la transaccion
                tr = conn.BeginTransaction();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

                cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into student (Name,Address,Mobile,Email ) values (@Name,@Address,@Mobile,@Email)", conn,tr);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into courses (Course,Name,Amount ) values (@Course,@Name1,@Amount )", conn,tr);               
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name1", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course",ddlCourse.SelectedValue.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount",txtAmount.Text);              
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                tr.Commit();
                cmd.Dispose();
                ShowMessage("Student Course Enrollment Successfully......!");
                clear();
                BindStudentGridView(); BindCoursesGridView();
            }             
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                ShowMessage(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Lo probare haber que tal. Gracias por el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Estimado Benjamín, puedes usar el siguiente código cuando ejecutas varias sentencias, aquí te presento en forma genérica el uso de un select y un insert.

```
MySqlCommand selCmd = con.CreateCommand();
MySqlCommand insCmd = con.CreateCommand();
selCmd.CommandText = "select ...";
insCmd.CommandText = "insert ...";
MySqlTransaction sqlTran = con.BeginTransaction();
try {
    selCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;
    insCmd.Transaction = sqlTran...selectCmd.ExecuteScalar()......;
    insCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()...
    sqlTran.Commit();
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
       //Sentencias 
       sqlTran.Rollback;
}
```

Comment: Gracias. Probare el código y veré como anda, aprecio la ayuda.